# Binary Search Program returning wrong position

Tags: java, algorithm, search, binary, binary-search

I  wrote a recursion program for binary search as you see  I am trying to find the position of the target =21 in the given array which sohould return me position as 2. However my output is 1. While I debug the it matches att arr[start]=target, However it straight was jumps to the line  findTheNumber(arr, mid + 1, end, target); then next line and then return mid..  Just wondering why my return is breaking off at the "return start"

```
 package Recursion;

 public class BinarySearch {
 static int  mid = 0;

 public static int findTheNumber(int[] arr, int start, int end, int target) {


    if (arr[start] == target) {
        return start;
    }

    mid = (start + end) / 2;

    if (arr[mid] == target) {
        return mid;
    } 

    if (target >arr[mid]) {
            findTheNumber(arr, mid + 1, end, target);
        } else if (target <arr[mid]) {
            findTheNumber(arr, start, mid-1, target);
        }
        return mid;
    }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 10, 12,21 };
    int start = 0;
    int end = arr.length - 1;

    int target = 21;

    System.out.println(findTheNumber(arr, start, end, target));

}
```

}

Comment: Also, there's a `binarySearch` method in `Arrays` (actually about four of them, iirc).  I assume this is a class assignment?

Comment: Not a class  assigment just trying to learn Data Structure and Algorthims

Comment: Well, in production code, just be aware that many of these sorts of problems are already solved and you should use a debugged solution.  Also take a look at the Apache Software Foundation and various Google code repositories: https://commons.apache.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (target >arr[mid]) {
    findTheNumber(arr, mid + 1, end, target);
} else if (target <arr[mid]) {
    findTheNumber(arr, start, mid-1, target);
}
```

You're just returning your `mid` point there, not the actual result of the recursive call.
Your code should look like:

```
if (target >arr[mid]) {
    return findTheNumber(arr, mid + 1, end, target);
} else if (target <arr[mid]) {
    return findTheNumber(arr, start, mid-1, target);
}
```

Comment: Thye programmed worked  i modified the code  like the below  if (target >arr[mid]) {
   return findTheNumber(arr, mid + 1, end, target);
   } else if (target <arr[mid]) {
   return  findTheNumber(arr, start, mid-1, target);
   }
   return mid;
  }

Comment: However I am trying to understand why the return statment should be given before the recursive call?

Comment: I am unable to avoid return statement mid .. as method says no return statement

Comment: Oh my fault, it seems I messed up with the brackets.

Comment: Marked as answer, @WolverinDEV,   I am just trying to understand is thumb rule like we need to have return next to recursive call?

Comment: Depends on how you actually want to pass the result. In your case, the last recursive function call with actually finds the index returns the index. So you've to propagate this result back to the top. Instead of returning the variable you could also declare a variable somewhere else (outside the method) and write the result into that variable. And when you've finished your call get your result from there ;) (But usually the method for recursive calls is the "return thing")

Comment: okay, How do I get rid  of  return mid  .. it is of no use,if i dont add that , it does not match with method signature and shows no return stament

Comment: There is a need, because when `if (target >arr[mid])` does not evaluate to true it implies that you've actually found the index and you've to return it ;) As said I removed the return mid accidentally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211735/discussion-between-shahul-ha-and-wolverindev).